# How to remove items from wishlist collection in magento

Tags: magento

In Magento, I want to remove or delete the wishlist items of a currently logged in user. 
Presently I am selecting the wishlist items by enabling the check boxes, and then delete them by using Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete(). The code snippet I have used is pasted below. When I click the submit button, items get deleted but the effect is only visible when I refresh the page again. The problem is I need to forcibly refresh the page so to see the items deleted. 
Can anybody suggest me any suitable solution. That will be appreciated.

Note: When check box is selected, wishlist-item id is assigned to its value field as:

value= $item->getWishlistItemId()

After form submission, following code executes

```
    if(isset($_POST['wishlist']))  // wishlist is name of check box.
    {
      $checkboxes = $_POST['wishlist'];
   foreach ($checkboxes as $id):      
      $bulk = $_COOKIE["bulkaction"];
      if($bulk == "Remove"):
      Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();   // $id contains the wishlist item id.
      $url = $this->getBaseUrl().'wishlist';
      header("refresh:0.0000000000001;", $url);
      endif;
  endforeach;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want to delete all wishlist items associated with a particular user? ...

```
$customerId = 1; // Replace with the customer id you are targetting

$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);

foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

Comment: Point of Clarification: This seems like it would delete the product from the database and not just delete it from the collection object. I'm confident that deleting the item from the database would be the wrong intent here.

Answer (score 0):

Drew's answer would definitely delete items from database. 
However if you would like to remove items from "current" collection you should use Varien_Data_Collection::removeItemByKey()

```
$items = $this->getItems();
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($condition) $items->removeDataByKey($key);
}
```

But please note that sometimes (when collection is accessed separately in different places in code) it might look like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($condition) $items->removeItemByKey($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if (!empty($collection)) {
        foreach ($collection as $k => $product) {
            $collection->removeItemByKey($k);
        }
    } else {
        return $collection;
    }
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.