# Magento remove the product in wishlist

Tags: magento

I can able to remove all items in wishlist, but how do i remove individual items from wishlist

The following is the code, to remove all items in wishlist:

```
public function removeWishList($customer_id,$product_id)
    {           
        $itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
            ->addCustomerIdFilter($customer_id);                            

        foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
            //Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($product_id)->delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know there is a "remove from wishlist" link in the wishlist page in standard magento ? Take a look a the controller/models involved and you have your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Hi use this code to remove a product having productid **$productId** of a customer having customerid **$customerId**.

```
**$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);
    foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
         if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productId){
            $item->delete();
         }
    }**
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard method for removing items from a wishlist in Magento:

```
Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerId = 1; // Replace with the customer id you are targetting

$itemCollection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId);

foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
    $item->delete();
}
```

[Moreinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790110/how-to-remove-items-from-wishlist-collection-in-magento)